# a mini as3 to java converter

Tags: java, eclipse, actionscript-3, converters

I want to convert a as3 project to java, and I came accross this blog: http://www.borisvanschooten.nl/blog/2011/05/01/a-mini-actionscript-3-to-java-converter/
but I don't know how to use it.
Can someone help me?
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just run the code that it gives you.

Comment: Yes, it says, **Usage: java -jar as32j.jar <sourcefile>**. Run that in CMD.

Comment: Sorry but im very new to Java so can you be more specific

Comment: Run the command **java -jar as32j.jar <sourcefile>** in the Command Prompt Window. I tried it myself, and it's pretty hard. You might want to find some other way of doing this.